# Sluggish cursor

Tags: cursor

Satellite-L650 running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

Afraid the Dynabook webpage does not recognise my European L-650. It is PSK1EE-09S00REN.

I may unworthy of your help - an unskilled Ubuntu user. I can just about do a simple script but I prefer not to. I have been privileged to be a user for 7 or 8 years and hope to continue that way.

My little problem is that recently my cursor has developed a stutter. It works normally for a minute or two and they suddenly stops moving. I am not switching user. After a few seconds it starts to move again. Is there something wrong that I have done? I am not aware of changing any settings.

If this doesn't deserve a reply, I can live with the "feature".

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Your laptop could have several different CPUs from the i3 on up. Would you please go to https://support.dynabook.com/support/modelHome?freeText=1200012489 and enter your model number there to find the specs of your particular version of the Satellite-L650? Then, please click [edit] and let us know what you have.

Comment: I can report that the problem is now solved, not by running scripts but by acquiring a new mouse. I was advised that they can get "tired" over time. There could be a way of re-rejuvenating the old mouse but simple cleaning was not the answer. So this is not an Ubuntu matter and I would like to close the question.